# JavaScript: Getting a Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'title' before initialization

Tags: javascript, object-destructuring

I am newbie to JavaScript. Here's the sample code.

```
let options = {
  title: "Menu",
  width: 100,
  height: 200
};

console.log(options.title);
let {title, width, height} = { options:title, options:width, options:height}; // clause 1
```

I am getting Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'title' before initialization on clause 1.

Why? The object options is initialized and hence i was able to print the options.title.

Again. Sorry for asking stupid question.
Thanks.

Comment: `let {title, width, height} = options;`

Comment: The [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) should be `let {title, width, height} = options`.

Comment: you can print `options.title` but `options:title` is different

Comment: i know this let {title, width, height} = options would work. I am just curious why the above does not work when the following works  let {height, width, title} = { title: "Menu", height: 200, width: 100 } ??

Comment: Because `{ options:title, options:width, options:height }` isn't valid JS. @yapkm01

Comment: Surely you can see what's different between `{ title: "Menu", height: 200, width: 100 }` and `{ options: title, options: width, options: height}`. If for some reason you'd want to create a new object then it should be `{ title: options.title, width: options.width, height: options.height}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `let {title, width, height} = { options:title, options:width, options:height}`, the `options: title` part is trying to create an object property called `options`, setting its value using an in-scope `title` variable. The only `title` variable in your code is the one being defined by that `let`. The initializer on the right-hand side of that `=` is evaluated when the `title` variable has been *declared* but before it's *initialized* (ready to be used), so you get that reference error.

It's like doing this, which tries to use `value` after it's *declared* (because `let` declarations are hoisted to the top of their block) but before it's *initialized* (because `let` declarations aren't initialized until they're reached in the step-by-step execution of the code):

```js
console.log(value);
let value = 42;
```

---

I suspect you just wanted to use `options`, so you got those values from the object you assigned to `options` earlier in the code:

```
let {title, width, height} = options;
```

Alternatively, from [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76121526/javascript-getting-a-uncaught-referenceerror-cannot-access-title-before-init/76121579#comment134245132_76121526), you may have meant to use `options.title` (note the `.`, not `:`) as a `title` in the object literal:

```
let {title, width, height} = { title: options.title, width: options.width, height: options.height};
//                      Colon −−−−−−^        ^−−− dot
```

That also works (though there's no need for that object literal).

Comment: Your explanation is amazing!! Appreciate much :O)